# Combine Form Submit button with Dialog submit button

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

Thanks for taking a look at my question here..

I have a dialog box that i have opening and the form that i have there works and gets the recurly key that i want. but i would like to replace the form button with the button that is with the Jquery UI dialog box button

at the moment i have to use both buttons... Form button (BLACK ARROW) to get the Recurly Key(Yellow Arrow) and then the Submit payment button (GREEN ARROW) to actually submit the form to the server...

i have 2 sets of javascript that is being used for this operation... i am tring to figure out how to combine them into the Submit payment button(Green Button) and not have to have 2 seperate buttons

Code Is below picture:

[image: Credit Card Dialog Box]

I believe i am on jquery 1.11.1

**Gems**

```
gem 'jquery-rails' 
gem 'jquery-ui-themes' 
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

**Dialog script (in application.js)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $("#pay_window").dialog({
           autoOpen: false,
           width: 600,
            buttons: {
                "Submit Payment": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/payment",
                        data: $("#PaymentForm").find([company_id, billing_email, first_name, last_name, recurly_token, plan]).serialize(),
                        type: "POST",
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert('Payment Completed')
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert('error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                }
            }
        //$(this).dialog("close");
        });
        $("#pay_button").on("click", function() {
            $("#pay_window").dialog("open");
        });
    });
});
```

**Form script (in the html of the form)**

```
  <script>
    // Configure recurly.js
    recurly.configure('<%= @recurly_public_key %>');

    $('form').on('submit', function (event) {

        javascript: $.each($('#postal_code, #year, #month, #number, #first_name, #last_name, #billing_email'), function(i, field) {
            $(field).css({ "border": '#FFFFFF 1px solid'});
        });


        var form = this;
        event.preventDefault();
        recurly.token(form, function (err, token) {
            if (err) {
              if (err.fields) {
                for (var i = 0, field; field = err.fields[i++];) {
                  $("#" + field).css({ "border": '#FF0000 2px solid'});
                }
              }

            } else {

                // recurly.js has filled in the 'token' field, so now we can submit the
                // form to your server; alternatively, you can access token.id and do
                // any processing you wish
                // form.submit();
            }
        });
    });

    recurly.token(document.querySelector('form'), tokenHandler);

    function tokenHandler (err, token) {
        if (err) {
            // handle error using err.code and err.fields
        } else {
            // handle success using token.id
        }
    }

    var pricing = recurly.Pricing();

    pricing.attach(document.querySelector('#pricing'));
</script>
```

**Form HTML coding**

```
<div id="pay_window" title="Payment Details">
<%= javascript_include_tag 'https://js.recurly.com/v3/recurly.js' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "creditcard" %>
<form id="PaymentForm">
<div class="payment">
  <section class="credit-card visa gr-visa">
    <ul class="inputs">
      <.. removed most of the form fields...>

      <input type="text" id="recurly_token" data-recurly="token" name="recurly_token" />
      <div align="center"><button>Get Token</button> </div>
    </ul>
  </section>

<div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: What "dialog" is it? There are countless jQuery dialog plugins

Comment: I believe i am on jquery 1.11.1 gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-themes'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'

Comment: So it is using jQuery UI dialog. :)

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default